# MoviePy can't terminate VideoClip process

Tags: python, moviepy

So, I've got this code

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import csv
    from moviepy.tools import cvsecs
    from yt_dlp import YoutubeDL
    import os
    import moviepy.editor as mpe
    from src.config.dev_config import download_video_location, temp_folder_path, csv_path
    from src.services.videos.double_video import process_split_video
    from src.services.videos.video import write_video_to_file
    from pytube import extract

    # Read CSV file into a set of tuples
    csv_set = set()
    with open(csv_path, 'r', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=';')
        header = next(csv_reader)
        for row in csv_reader:
            url, start_time = row
            url_id = extract.video_id(url)
            start_time = int(cvsecs(start_time))
            name = f"{str(url_id)}_{str(start_time)}"
            csv_set.add(name)

    # Read video files in the storage folder into a set of tuples
    storage_set = set()
    for filename in os.listdir(download_video_location):
        name = filename.split(".")[0]
        storage_set.add(name)

    # Calculate the difference between sets
    videos_to_download = csv_set - storage_set
    videos_to_delete = storage_set - csv_set

    # Download videos from videos_to_download
    for video in videos_to_download:
        video_start = int(video.split("_")[-1])
        video_id = "_".join(video.rsplit("_", 1)[:-1])
        video_url = f"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={video_id}"

        params = {
            "outtmpl": os.path.join(temp_folder_path, f"%(id)s.%(ext)s"),
            "format_sort": [f"res:720"],
            "format": "bv",
            "noplaylist": True,
        }

        with YoutubeDL(params) as ydl:
            info = ydl.extract_info(video_url, download=True)
            path = ydl.prepare_filename(info)

        clip = mpe.VideoFileClip(path).without_audio()
        clip = process_split_video(clip)

        subclip = clip.subclip(video_start, video_start + 60)
        write_video_to_file(subclip, f"{video_id}_{video_start}")

        clip.close()
        clip = None

    # Delete videos from videos_to_delete
    for video in videos_to_delete:
        file_to_delete = [file for file in os.listdir(download_video_location) if file.startswith(video)]

        if file_to_delete:
            file_to_delete = file_to_delete[0]
            filepath_to_delete = os.path.join(download_video_location, file_to_delete)

            try:
                os.remove(filepath_to_delete)
                print(f"File {file_to_delete} deleted successfully.")
                break
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error deleting file {file_to_delete}: {str(e)}")
```

In the last loop it should delete all the files from the videos_to_delete set, but there is an error

```
Error deleting file n_Dv4JMiwK8_178.mp4: [WinError 32] Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, так как этот файл занят другим процессом: 'C:\\Users\\nikita_turda\\PycharmProjects\\job\\storage\\n_Dv4JMiwK8_178.mp4'
```

I tried using clip.close(), as you can see. Also I tried commenting this loop

```
    # Download videos from videos_to_download
    for video in videos_to_download:
        video_start = int(video.split("_")[-1])
        video_id = "_".join(video.rsplit("_", 1)[:-1])
        video_url = f"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={video_id}"

        params = {
            "outtmpl": os.path.join(temp_folder_path, f"%(id)s.%(ext)s"),
            "format_sort": [f"res:720"],
            "format": "bv",
            "noplaylist": True,
        }

        with YoutubeDL(params) as ydl:
            info = ydl.extract_info(video_url, download=True)
            path = ydl.prepare_filename(info)

        clip = mpe.VideoFileClip(path).without_audio()
        clip = process_split_video(clip)

        subclip = clip.subclip(video_start, video_start + 60)
        write_video_to_file(subclip, f"{video_id}_{video_start}")

        clip.close()
        clip = None
```

To see if it's the case, but this doesn't work also.

Other functions that are used

```
def process_split_video(clip, strict_size: bool = True):
    # crop to (9, 8) because it's half of (9, 16)
    result = video.crop_to_ratio(clip, (9, 8))
    result = video.resize_height(result, 1920 / 2, strict_size=strict_size)
    return result
```

and

```
def write_video_to_file(clip, name_without_extension):
    output_path = dev_config.video_output_path
    os.makedirs(output_path, exist_ok=True)
    clip.write_videofile(f"{output_path}/{name_without_extension}.mp4")
```

Comment: You're not showing the rest of the functions - for all we know, process_split_video and write_video_to_file are keeping those file handles open.

Comment: Sorry, fixed that

Comment: Considering that commenting out that one section did not fix your issue, I would also try confirming with Resource Monitor that another process is not causing issues and holding up that file. E.g. a forgotten/ hanging python process from an earlier test.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that right now. The proccess that is still using files - ffmpeg-win64-v4.2.2.exe. what should I do in this situation?

Comment: I found out what is the problem - clip = process_split_video(clip). The code works fine when i remove this method